# How can i change translateX value when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm new to react. I wanna make my button change the translateX value when it is clicked by amount of 1170px, but when i checked the site i quite don't get how the onClick attribute is rendered in reactjs.

Here is the code:

```
function Slideshow() {
  const slider = [
    { name: slide_logo_1, link: "https://timesrecords.lnk.to/CITOPIA" },
    {
      name: slide_logo_2,
      link: "https://store.hangdiathoidai.com/search?q=lana+del+rey",
    },
    { name: slide_logo_3, link: "https://timesrecords.lnk.to/TocTien-Cong" },
    { name: slide_logo_4, link: "https://timesrecords.lnk.to/TSMidnights" },
    { name: slide_logo_5, link: "https://timesrecords.lnk.to/LINK-HTL" },
  ];
  const getTranslateX = () => {
    var myElement = document.querySelector(".owl-wrapper");
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(myElement);
    var matrix = new DOMMatrix(style.transform);
    <Alert>{matrix}</Alert>
    
  };

  return (
    <section>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div className="inner space-30 section-slider">
          <div
            className="slider-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme"
            id="slider-carousel"
            data-mobile="[479,1]"
            data-tabletsmall="[768,1]"
            data-desktopsmall="[979,1]"
            data-desktop="[1199,1]"
            data-pagination="false"
            data-navigation="true"
            data-autoplay="5000"
            data-items="1"
            style={{ display: "block", opacity: 1 }}
          >
            <div
              className="owl-wrapper-outer autoHeight"
              style={{ height: 431 }}
            >
              <div
                className="owl-wrapper"
                style={{
                  width: 11700,
                  left: 0,
                  display: "block",
                  transition: `all 400ms ease 0s`,
                  transform: `translate3d(0px, 0, 0)`,
                }}
              >
                {slider.map((products, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="owl-item" style={{ width: 1170 }}>
                      <div className="text-center">
                        <Link
                          className="slide"
                          to={products.link}
                          title=""
                          key={index}
                        >
                          <img src={products.name} alt="" />
                        </Link>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div className="owl-controls clickable">
              <div className="owl-buttons">
                <div
                  className="sangtrai owl-prev"
                  onClick={getTranslateX}
                ></div>
                <div className="sangphai owl-next"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Slideshow;
```

The thing in here is when i click **.sangtrai**, the translateX value in **.owl-wrapper's transform** will be added by amount of **1170px** and when i click **.sangphai**, the translateX value in **.owl-wrapper's transform** will be reduced by amount of **1170px**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only recommend that you split this functionality and create separate functions for this. Also a touch of state management may help here as well.

Add state and separate functions for maintaining the x value:

```
  const [translateX, setTranslateX] = useState(0);

  const handlePrevClick = () => {
    setTranslateX(translateX + 1170);
  };

  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setTranslateX(translateX - 1170);
  };
```

Then update the div with .slider-carousel to use this state value:

```
  <div className="owl-wrapper" style={{
    width: 11700,
    left: 0,
    display: "block",
    transition: `all 400ms ease 0s`,
    transform: `translate3d(${translateX}px, 0, 0)`,
  }}>
```

and finally call seperate functions on the seperate events:

```
<div className="sangtrai owl-prev" onClick={handlePrevClick}></div>
<div className="sangphai owl-next" onClick={handleNextClick}></div>
```

**Note**: I haven't tested the code above but it may be an approach that can help if it doesn't work as expected. Cheers!